# strange behavior when starting activity from notification

Tags: android, android-intent, notifications

I am using Parse to send notification to Android phones and when I receive push I will generate a notification using the below function.

```
private void generateNotification(Context context, String title, Intent intent, boolean hasSound) {
    int NOTIFICATION_ID = ("onccent" + System.currentTimeMillis()).hashCode();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, NOTIFICATION_ID, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    NotificationManager mNotifM = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher).setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name)).setContentText(title);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    if (!hasSound) {
        mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    }
    mNotifM.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());

}
```

The intent is a intent of a activity displaying messages and let's call it Activity B. I will use Activity A to represent the home activity.

The problem is: when A exists, all things work well. When I click a notification, the stack becomes

```
A -> B1
```

And click another:

```
A -> B1 -> B2
```

This is what I expect. However, when I *kill* the whole app and then click on the first notification. It will open a B but the following notification will only bring my app to front without open a new B.

It seems something will not work without A. I manage to open A first if A does not exist in the stack so that define A as the parent activity of B. The notification works but it seems all previous activity goes away.

How can I solve this? In short, I just want that a new activity will open when I click on the notification.